# Close the alert javascript without refresh page using Codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I build form which validation using javascript and Codeigniter 3.04. here is my HTML code

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" onsubmit="check()">
  //code
</form>
```

I will check length character in my function javascript before insert into database. here my function

```
function check(){
    var title = document.getElementById('txt_check').value.length;
    if (title <= 50) {
      alert("The title length less than 50 Character ");    
    }
}
```

When alert show, and then I click OK, all data in my previous form is clear, so I must write it again. When I using Codeigniter 2.00, it doesn't happen, but in this new version, everything refresh, I think all cache was reset. Can you help me to remove this "refresh" only this page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your function as you did, but you have to make sure that the alert dialog stopps the form from beeing sent!

So insert `return` before the function is called:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" onsubmit="return check();">
  //code
</form>
```

And make the function return something:

```
function check(){
    var title = document.getElementById('txt_check').value.length;
    if (title <= 50) {
      alert("The title length less than 50 Character ");    
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
   }
}
```

So if the function return false the Browser won't send the form, only if the function returns true it will send the form.
And if the form is not sent, the values won't be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You are submiting the form try add this lines of code:

```
$("#my-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

   var title = document.getElementById('txt_check').value.length;
   if (title <= 50) {
       alert("The title length less than 50 Character ");    
   }
});
```

And add an Id to the form:

```
<form id="my-form" class="form-horizontal"  method="POST">
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but It works If i using codeigniter 2.00, or maybe I disable something in this framework at first?

Comment: If you are going to do that might as well remove the `onsubmit` and do all the business in one submit handler

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not an issue related to Codeigniter.
You just need to prevent the form from getting submitted.
**Remove `onSubmit="check()"` and add this code in your javascript file.**

```
$(".form-horizontal").submit(function(e){
    var title = $('#txt_check').val();
    if(title.length<=50){
        alert('Title length is short');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also, please double-check that you are using `id="txt_check"` and not class. `#` is used for id. And dot `.` is used for class.

Comment: Ow okay, so this is not codeigniter problem. but I feel different with CI 2 , especially when I click back to previous page. But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Fatchul Yes. Anytime!